# Attach NSMenu to NSStatusItem with Storyboard

Tags: xcode, macos, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

I am trying to attach an `NSMenu` item to a `NSStatusItem` to have a menu when clicking on my Menu Bar App for Mac OS.

I am new to Mac programming and I searched tutorials on the Web. However, all the material I found involves the usage of the file Xib to add the `NSMenu` and linking it to the existing code. However, I don't have such a file in my project, it only includes the storyboard file.

I hope you can help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a menu programmatically and set it to `NSStatusItem` like this.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    _statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:30];
    _statusItem.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"..."];

    // create menu
    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
    NSMenuItem *item1 = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"menu1" action:@selector(menu1Action:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    NSMenuItem *item2 = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"menu2" action:@selector(menu2Action:) keyEquivalent:@""];

    [menu addItem:item1];
    [menu addItem:item2];

    [_statusItem setMenu:menu]; // attach
}
```

Of course, you can use `NSMenu` as outlet. To do that, drag `NSMenu` to Application Scene in the storyboard, and connect it to AppDelegate's outlet.